# Is the ideal $(1+\sqrt{-6})$ maximal in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is the ideal $(1+\sqrt{-6})$ maximal in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$? I think yes. Here is my proof.

> We have that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-6}] \cong \mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+6).$ The ideal then corresponds to the ideal $(1+x).$ Thus, by the Isomorphism Theorem, we have that $$\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+6)/(1+x,x^2+6)/(x^2+6) \cong \mathbb Z[x]/(1+x,x^2+6).$$ Now, $x(1+x)=x^2+x$ implies that $(x^2-6)-(x^2+x)=-x-6.$ Thus, we have the equality of the ideals $(1+x,x^2+6)=(1+x,x+6)=(1+x,5),$ and so, ultimately, we get $\mathbb Z[x]/(5,1+x) \cong \mathbb Z_5[x]/(1+x) \cong \mathbb Z_5,$ which is a field. Is this correct?

I have two technical doubts, which I just need explained, but I believe the proof is fine.

First is identifying $(1+x, x^2+6)$ in the quotient ring with the ideal $(1+x, x^2+6)$ in the big ring. Can we always do that with principal ideals? Is it true that $(a) + (b)$ is always $(a,b)$?

Second is all the subtracting of ideals. I algebraically proved that the two ideals are still equal after such operations, but I just want to make sure that it is always allowed. If I have $(a,b),$ is it true that this ideal is equal to $(a-y,b-x),$ where $y \in (b)$ and $x \in (a)?$

Comment: $(2,6)=(2)$ is not equal to $(2-6,6-2)=(4)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Fair enough, you have to do it one at a time. And it mirror calculating the gcd in integers!

Comment: Somewhere your $x^2+6$ became $x^2-6$.

Answer (score 3):

It's a sound approach: indeed
$$\frac{\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]}{(1+\sqrt{-6})}\cong\frac{\Bbb Z[X]}{(1+X,X^2+6)}$$
but since
$$X^2+6-(X-1)(X+1)=7$$ then
$$\frac{\Bbb Z[X]}{(1+X,X^2+6)}=\frac{\Bbb Z[X]}{(1+X,7)}\cong\frac{\Bbb Z}{(7)}$$
the finite field of seven elements, so that the ideal is prime.

Comment: In fact, it is maximal.